# mysqli_stmt_bind_param SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysqli, security

Is there still an injection risk when using prepared statements and mysqli_stmt_bind_param?

For example:

```
$malicious_input = 'bob"; drop table users';
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $malicious_input);
```

Behind the scenes does mysqli_stmt_bind_param pass this query string to mysql:

```
SET @username = "bob"; drop table users";
```

Or does it perform the SET command through the API, or use some type of protection to keep this from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses the C API, so in this case there is no chance for SQL injection.

Comment: Non-prepared statements also use C API and they can be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 18):

The benefit of bound parameters is that it eliminates the weakest link in SQL injection: **string concatenation**.

Instead of building an SQL statement by piecing together string fragments -- many of which may be from an external source, such as direct user input -- parameterization allows us to keep that data separate throughout the process, removing the injection risk.

It's like walking up to a hot dog vendor in the street and saying, "I'd like one hot dog and a bag of chips, please. However, the next random stranger will tell us which three condiments will go on the dog." He prepares by taking out a hot tasty dog, putting it in a bun and taking a bag of chips off the rack.

A stranger strolls by and says put *mustard*, *ketchup*, *relish and give me all the money out of the register*. Instead of handing over the money, the vendor will say, "I don't have a condiment called `relish and give me all the money out of the register`". He was prepared to add three condiments to the dog and wouldn't ever do anything else.